# How can i access detail of a file in Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, drive

How can i access detail of a file in Google Drive ? ?

Example:

```
from google.colab import drive
from glob import glob

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

images=glob(r'/content/gdrive/My Drive/img/*')
```

I would like to recover the information when which images was upload to Drive, like time and day.